# Realm Migration with new foreign field

Tags: android, realm, realm-migration

I have created a new realm object (B), and a new field in an existing realm object (A), which references to the new object B. In my migration file, I have this:

```
if(!realm.getSchema().contains("B")) {
    realm.getSchema().create("B").addField("name", String.class).addField("resId", int.class);
}

RealmObjectSchema schemaA = realm.getSchema().get("A");

if (!schemaA .hasField("referenceToB")) {
    schemaA .addField("referenceToB", B.class);
}
```

It does not work, and I get: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Realm doesn't support this field type: B

How can I create this new field in A referencing to B in my migration file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per documentation, to add a link field, you need to use [realmObjectSchema.addRealmObjectField()](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmObjectSchema.html#addRealmObjectField-java.lang.String-io.realm.RealmObjectSchema-) instead of `addField()`.

```
if (!schemaA.hasField("referenceToB")) {
    RealmObjectSchema bSchema = schema.get("B");
    schemaA.addRealmObjectField("referenceToB", bSchema);
}
```

Comment: Thanks you so much.